Where can I ask this question about Computer Screen Technology?
I have asked a question about Computer Screens on Super User. Specifically, about understanding their (supposedly different) technology, certainly not a question about their use as computer screens (much less anything else).
After various edits the wording is.

How are NanoLED and MicroLED computer screens designed differently?
Mokubai said that

You can clearly see the difference just by looking at the LED stages.
One has single colour elements, the other shows a lot of little dots

I don't undestand what single colour elements vs a lot (some tens
after focusing on a particular part of each of the 3 RGB element) of
little dots means. Does this imply that in Microled each band
(element) is made up of one single pixel?

The NanoLED trademark seems to indicate that the issue is probably marketing, and not different design or materials: 


I don't see a difference since both are allegedly self-emmissive and turn electricity into light
Other than the different emmiter name, I can't see anything different.




I want to know where would the correct place of asking such a question be.
I understand the question is more about the technology itself and less about how it "interfaces" with the Computer.

If I understood correctly what Mokubai said that would push it into Electrical Engineering.SE territory. I was asked (with the previous wording that asked how they were different instead of how they were designed differently) how is the question a design question (it seems to be a necessary condition for Electrical Engineering.SE)
But there are many questions not tagged with neither design nor circuit design (plus my new wording asks about how do these 2 panel technologies differ in their design)
led, display, diode, optics, optoelectronics are other tags that are used without those previous 2.
Engineering.SE has given me no feedback in these 8 days. I could think of the tags Mechanical Engineering, Electrical Engineering, Materials, Chemical Engineering, Design.
The Super User META question is
How strictly is "interfaces" interpreted; even if the question is off-topic here shouldn't it be considered a candidate for migration?


I want to know where would the correct place of asking such a question be.

So far, judging by the comments, we've determined that the question is:

Off topic on Super User - (Closed & Deleted)
Off topic for Electrical Engineering (Meta Post)
On topic for Engineering (Meta Post)

Could the question have been migrated?
Yeah, probably. But that's irrelevant now. To migrate it, a mod would have to undelete it, reopen it, then re-close it as Migrate to -> Engineering SE. But for what benefit? Migrating the post doesn't "move" it, it duplicates it onto the new site, and locks the old one for 30 days, before it is deleted. The only other thing that happens is an entry is added into the audit history (timeline) of the new post, stating that it was migrated. Like this one, for example.
So yeah, it could've been migrated, but it wasn't. Next time, perhaps. At this point, it would be a lot less hassle to simply re-ask the question on the appropriate site.

Sicne they single handedly closed it is is fair to expect them to reopen it. The benefit it mostly self-satisfaction. The question is if it could shouldn't it?

@George the sites functions don't exist for self-satisfaction - they exist to maintain the site. That a question got closed and deleted instead of migrated, locked and eventually auto-deleted is inconsequential - what matters is: can you get an answer for your question here? No. Can your question live somewhere else on the network? yes.

The other reason is badges and question-limit. A Closed or Deleted question often counts against you while a migrated question does not. Badges are here for a reason too.

A single deleted question isn't going to weigh much against your account, and badges fall under the 'self satisfaction' umbrella: ultimately nice to have, but not essential. Are you asking your LED display question for the badges, or are you asking your question out of genuine interest/curiosity?

It is not about weighing much. If it weighs at all (even the least) that is enough. Badges are a feature of the site. So maybe the functions of the site exist partly for self-satisfaction (why are there badges then if as you said the fall under the "self satisfaction" umbrella when as you said the function don't exist for self-satisfaction).

@GeorgeNtoulos No, I don't consider badges as site functions. They aren't an action someone takes to maintain the site. They're an award system for encouragement, nothing more. But now we're off on a tangent. The point is that earning badges, or having a deleted question on your account, aren't a good enough reason to dredge up a post that isn't relevant to this community. But we don't need to rehash this further right? You've received the opinions of multiple community members and mods at this point - if we can't convince you I don't know what will :)

One can read everywhere that deletion is a last resort when the question can't be salvaged in any way. People voted to delete it instead of migrating it. A deleted question is heavier than a closed question. So voting is arbitrary.

what matters is: can you get an answer for your question here? No. Can your question live somewhere else on the network? yes. Some persons prematurely killed it even though it could live somewhere else on the network.

@GeorgeNtoulos migration is deletion with extra steps. It's still deleted on this site.

Automatically deleted not deleted by the community.
