Where can I make requests to reopen questions on the Super User main Stack Exchange?
I'm asking about the scope of the tag reopen-request here, on Meta.
I had such a request closed as off-topic and I don't understand why.
Why was it closed?
I am basically asking why the question it was considered a duplicate of was closed.

@JoepvanSteen The issue was the scope of the meta. Where can make requests to reopen questions on Superuser main Stackexchange?

@JoepvanSteen Because I made one such request and it was closed as off-topic. I could edit the question accordingly if you belieave I should.

@JoepvanSteen If it was discussed ad nauseam so be it. It was closed as off-topic and in this question I am asking about the scope of the meta (where do I make such requests).

Where to make such requests? Here. So if you have a question you think is closed yet should be open, state your case here. For best effects, state it clearly.

@JoepvanSteen There is a very specific tag in Meta https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request. This question was not about How to reopen a question in the main site. This question asked about the scope of a meta tag.

@Mast Please post this as an answer that I can accept. But then why is https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15291/heavy-handed-moderation off-topic? Please discuss why the specific reopen-request is off-topic.

Ah, you were question banned there. That does change things.

@Mast I was not question banned in SuperUser, Engineering, Electrical Engineering, Mathematics, StackOverflow, Meta.SE. I have been question banned in Medicine and Biology but I don't understand how that changes anything (these sites are irrelevant to the question). I have not been question banned in SuperUser or any "candidate" for migration?

This is your 3rd meta on the topic of how your question was handled: 1, 2. The question was closed, passed through the review queues multiple times, and was deleted. You asked around, and found that it's on-topic for Engineering. But rather than re-ask the question on Engineering, you're wasting time arguing about it not being migrated. Or claiming mods were being heavy handed/pedantic. Or worrying about rate limits on asking. All of that time spent could have instead been spent posting your actual question about LED screens over on Engineering.

@Robotnik I had asked in the Engineering.SE more than a couple of days before people voted to delete it. music2myear, Giacomo1968, Toto deleted it. It wasn't automatically deleted. They didn't even wait for the straight simple answer. People should have asked around before deleting to close it.

@Robotnik The three questions are different. This one is asking about the scope of the reopen-request tag in the Meta site.  https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15291/heavy-handed-moderation This question was a reopen-request. https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15290/where-can-i-ask-this-question-about-computer-screen-technology. This question was about the place to ask the question (asking about the scope of the main site might be more fitting to describe the question)

@GeorgeNtoulos - Here is where you ask to have something reopened, once you ask and a discussion is had, you eventually have to drop the subject of the community ends of not believing the question should be reopened. You know that behavior, you asked that should be avoided, asking a third time for a question that is out of scope to be reopened only so it can be migrated is that behavior you should stop. Stop asking for the question to be reopened.

@Giacomo1968 I am not trying to change the behavior of Stack Exchange sites.

@Ramhound Please post answers as answers. The sole reopen request https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15291/heavy-handed-moderation was closed as off topic. It was considered of topic. It was the only reopen request. It wasn't even marked as a duplicate but off topic. I asked once for it to be reopened not thrice.

@Giacomo1968 Shame on the prejudiced. Blame them not me.

@GeorgeNtoulos If (if!) you are trolling then you're pretty good at it, because I'm 90% convinced you are not trolling. If you are not trolling then I'm letting you know your modus operandi looks like sophisticated trolling to me. Of course we shall in good faith assume you are not trolling (and I can see how this would be perfect if (if!) you were trolling). Anyway, be aware there is the duck test.

@Giacomo1968 I did not get "No!" for an answer I got no answer. Instead I got closure. As for the prejudice it belongs to the prejudiced. I have no prejudice. I am making every effort possible to understand how these communities work.

@GeorgeNtoulos - “I asked once for it to be reopened not thrice.” - Every time you edited the question and selected the option to put it in the reopen queue also counts as asking to reopen it. Your meta question asking to reopen the question was closed because you received an answer it would not accept that answer. I am not going to entertain this conversation by submitting an answer. You already have a solution to the problem, repost the question at the correct Community, reopening your question won’t happen

@Ramhound We are on the meta site. I was limited to reopen-requests. Questions with the tag in meta. "because you received an answer it would not accept that answer. " Word salad. It would not accept that answer? Who would not accept which answer?

@GeorgeNtoulos - I would have just reposted my question.

@JoepvanSteen I am basically asking why the question it was considered a duplicate of was closed. People just need this question closed. They don't care whether it is actually a duplicate. How exactly is it a duplicate?


Where can I make requests to reopen questions on the Super User main Stack Exchange?

Right here on Meta Super User. This is what the tag guidance says for reopen-request:

Requests to have closed questions reopened by community or a moderator. Please include arguments – why should the question be reopened?



I had such a request closed as off-topic and I don't understand why.

Your question is not a reopen request. For starters, you don't give an actual request (or reasons) to reopen it. Second, is the fact that the question is titled "Heavy Handed Moderation", and you spend the majority of the question body calling out a moderator's actions as "unwarranted pedantry". You added a sentence requesting it get migrated (not reopened, btw) as a secondary point to the rant - after it was already closed.
For it to be a request, you should

focus less on the actions taken thus far*
focus more on the actions you'd like to be taken moving forward.

For your specific circumstance, it would look something like this:


Please consider migrating this question to Engineering SE
I have the following question about LED screen technology [link to deleted question], which was closed as off-topic. Despite clarifying edits it remained closed, and is now deleted.
I have determined that it's on topic at Engineering SE [link to Engineering meta], and I'd like it to be migrated there. Can a moderator please undelete & migrate it there instead?
discussion migration


This is not a guarantee that the request would be handled the way you want it to be: It is possible that the requested action will be denied, and you should be prepared to accept that outcome.
Of course, all this is a fairly moot point, considering you can simply repost it on Engineering, as covered by your other post on the matter.
* This includes not calling out & judging individual community users or moderators for their actions.

Why is calling out or judging individual community users or moderators for their actions bad? Aren't we all accountable? Aren't the rules for everyone? I added the sentence to improve it. Probably it wasn't clear enough that it was a request.

There was the first line Can the community please migrate the question to Engineering.SE that also had a less direct wording. The first line was there since the first version of the question.

@GeorgeNtoulos - The answer to that direct question is No, it cannot be migrated, I mean it could be migrated but not in it's current state.  It would have to be undeleted, improved to the point where it was a quality question, then migrated.  You are better off just resubmitting the question at Engineering.SE

@Ramhound That doesn't make the Meta-question the reopen request. Off-topic.

@GeorgeNtoulos - Your meta question was closed, “This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community.”, when your question was about the moderator seeking input on how to modify your question.

@Ramhound My question was a reopen request from the first line (in every version since the very first). It sought input. Specifically **Can the community please migrate the question to Engineering.SE **. It was a reopen request plain and simple.

If I am not mistaken by the time you asked for it to be migrated it was already closed and potentially already deleted. By that point you were asking us to reopen a question only to close it by migrating it. The question then becomes why didn’t you just resubmit the question? Why did you insist on getting the question reopened considering any negative effects of the question existing will still be applied regardless if it’s migrated or not.

@GeorgeNtoulos - "Someone even said I engender prejudice." - Did you report this comment? The closure of your question has nothing to do with prejudice by the way, but if somebody were to suggest you "engender prejudice" then that would be considered an unfriendly comment.

@Ramhound https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15301/where-can-i-make-requests-to-reopen-questions-on-the-super-user-main-stack-excha#comment45661_15301 just above in the discussion
Giacomo1968 engender prejudice
https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15301/where-can-i-make-requests-to-reopen-questions-on-the-super-user-main-stack-excha#comment45664_15301 your prejudice seems to be well earned I just read above that you consider every time I editted the question a request (I did so the very first day)

@GeorgeNtoulos - So did you report the comment?

@Ramhound The first one seems to have been deleted. But if anything it could be considered friendly advice and evidence that the community is bigoted/prejudiced and vote arbitrarily. They are just fooling with me. Who can this be a duplicate as suggested? How can a direct reopen request be off topic (considering there is a specific tag for them)?

@Ramhound I read above https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15301/where-can-i-make-requests-to-reopen-questions-on-the-super-user-main-stack-excha/15302?noredirect=1#comment45671_15301 that you consider every time I edited the question the same as the reopen request in the Meta the same. I did so the very first day Mokubai arbitrarily decided to close the question single handedly.
